# Match a blank line in expect

Tags: expect

How can I match a blank line in expect?  `expect -r "" {send "y\n"}"` causes `y` to be entered immediately.

```
| 
| Type 'y' to accept:
| 
                          <---- match this blank line!
```

Comment: I think you probably need to match the consecutive newlines.

Comment: Yes, expect -r "\r\n\r\n" {send "y\n"} works.  Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: If I'd known it would work I would have. You tested it and got it working so you can do it and accept your own answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I wanted to give you credit though :)

Answer (score 1):

Etan Reisner's suggestion of matching consecutive newlines works.

```
expect -r "\r\n\r\n" {send "y\n"}
```